# Android app exits when launch another activity using registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, start-activity, registerforactivityresult

I have 2 classes MainActivity and EditActivity. I try to launch EditActivity with registerForActivityResult() in MainActivity but the app exits immediately; startActivity() works fine but registerForActivityResult() serves my purpose, which is returning result to MainActivity. The function that launches EditActivity is as below.

MainActivity.kt

```
fun launchEditView(position: Int) {
        val getResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val value = it.data?.getStringExtra("alternative")
                listOfTasks.set(position, value.toString())
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                saveItems()
            }
        }
        // first parameter is the context, second is the class of the activity to launch
        val intent = Intent(this, EditActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("taskName", listOfTasks.get(position))

        getResult.launch(intent)
    }
```

Update: the error is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.example.simpletodo.MainActivity@3a90598 is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.register(ActivityResultRegistry.java:123)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:682)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:691)
        at com.example.simpletodo.MainActivity.launchEditView(MainActivity.kt:86)
```

Comment: Please check android studio logcat for errors if any. I'd say your app is crashing probably.

Comment: @ShahnawazAnsari It is. I already posted the error.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you are doing wrong: you have to register ahead of time. Did you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register)?

Comment: You have to put it outside any method or overriding method. i.e before onCreate() method

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm sorry, I am new to Android dev. Can you explain what "register" in this context means? What do I have to "register"? And by "ahead of time", do you mean before I launch the intent?

Comment: You have to move `val getResult = ...` to outside any functions, as a class member.

Comment: @TylerV it works! Many thanks!

Comment: @ShahnawazAnsari It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as you see the logcat is that you are trying to register in a wrong state. You have to do it before that activity state comea to resumed state. So, to solve this issue you have to register in your onCreate method of your activity and hold the launcher instance. Then anytime you want to start another activity you can use it. As a sample code:

```
lateinit var launcher: ActivityResultLauncher

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //The common logic of onCreate method
    val launcher= registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val value = it.data?.getStringExtra("alternative")
                listOfTasks.set(position, value.toString())
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                saveItems()
            }
        }
}

fun launchEditView(position: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(this, EditActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("taskName", listOfTasks.get(position))
        launcher.launch(intent)
    }
```